# Scheme macro expansion: Nesting let-syntax inside define-syntax

Tags: macros, scheme, define-syntax

I wish to expand

```
(foo x (f n) (f n) (arbitrary) (f n) ...)
```

into

```
(begin (x 'f n) (x 'f n) (arbitrary) (x 'f n) ...)
```

my attempt is:

```
(define-syntax foo
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ l a ...)
     (let-syntax ((f (syntax-rules ()
                       ((_ n) (l (quote f) n)))))
       (begin a ...)))))

(define (x t1 t2) (cons t1 t2))   ;; for example only
(define (arbitrary) (cons 'a 'b)) ;; for example only
(foo x (f 1) (f 2) (arbitrary) (f 3))
```

Using a macro stepper I can see that the first stage of the macro expands to

```
(let-syntax ((f (syntax-rules () ((_ n) (x 'f n)))))
  (begin (f 1) (f 2) (arbitrary) (f 3)))
```

Which, when evaluated in isolation works perfectly, but when executed as a whole I get an error about `f` being an undefined identifier. I assume this is an issue in scoping, is this type of macro expansion possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, you need to get `f` from *somewhere* -- your macro just makes it up, and therefore it is not visible to users of `foo`.  When you do consider that you need to get it from somewhere, the question is where would you get it from?  Here's a fixed version of your code that assumes that it is the first thing in the second subform of `foo`:

```
(define-syntax foo
  (syntax-rules ()
    [(_ l (f a) more ...)
     (let-syntax ([f (syntax-rules ()
                       [(_ n) (l 'f n)])])
       (list (f a) more ...))]))

(define (x t1 t2) (cons t1 t2))
(define (arbitrary) (cons 'a 'b))
(foo x (f 1) (f 2) (arbitrary) (f 3))
```

(I also made it expand into a `list` to see that all forms are transformed.)

However, if you want a global kind of `f` to be used inside `foo`, then you really have to do just that: define a global `f`.  Here's a limited way to do that:

```
;; no body => using `f' is always an error
(define-syntax f (syntax-rules ()))

(define-syntax foo
  (syntax-rules ()
    [(_ l a ...) (list (foo-helper l a) ...)]))
(define-syntax foo-helper
  (syntax-rules (f) ; match on f and transform it
    [(_ l (f n)) (l 'f n)]
    [(_ l a)     a]))

(define (x t1 t2) (cons t1 t2))
(define (arbitrary) (cons 'a 'b))
(foo x (f 1) (f 2) (arbitrary) (f 3))
```

The main limitation in this is that it will only work if one of the `a` forms is using `f` -- but it won't work if it is nested in an expression.  For example, this will throw a syntax error:

```
(foo x (f 1) (f 2) (arbitrary)
       (let ([n 3]) (f n)))
```

You can imagine complicating `foo-helper` and make it scan its input recursively, but that's a slippery slope you don't want to get into.  (You'll need to make special cases for places like inside a `quote`, in a binding, etc.)

The way to solve that in Racket (and recently in Guile too) is to use a [syntax parameter](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/stxparam.html).  Think about this as binding `f` to the same useless macro using [`define-syntax-parameter`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/stxparam.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket/stxparam..rkt%29._define-syntax-parameter%29%29), and then use [`syntax-parameterize`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/stxparam.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket/stxparam..rkt%29._syntax-parameterize%29%29) to "adjust" its meaning inside a `foo` to a macro that does the transformation that you want.  Here's how this looks like:

```
;; needed to get syntax parameters
(require racket/stxparam)

;; same useless definition, but as a syntax parameter
(define-syntax-parameter f (syntax-rules ()))

(define-syntax foo
  (syntax-rules ()
    [(_ l a ...)
     ;; adjust it inside these forms
     (syntax-parameterize ([f (syntax-rules ()
                                [(_ n) (l 'f n)])])
       (list a ...))]))

(define (x t1 t2) (cons t1 t2))
(define (arbitrary) (cons 'a 'b))
(foo x (f 1) (f 2) (arbitrary)
       (let ([n 3]) (f n)))
```

Comment: I was hoping that the body of the top-level macro call would be passed as-is and evaluated in the scope of the expanded form, a scope in which `f` does exist. The solution you offer is not ideal as I intend the body of `foo` to contain a mixture of arbitrary expressions and known keyword expressions (such as `f`). You can probably tell that I am trying to make a cleaner interface to a traditional dispatcher, I may have to just rely on the dispatcher. Thanks.

Comment: I see now that this is an issue of macro hygiene, not of scope. `f` is not a known binding so a new, hygienic binding is created for internal use.

Comment: Macro hygiene *is* a scope problem: if you want a globally known `f`, then you need to ... do just that.  I've added two examples for doing that.